# Class Object is being referenced as a String

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing code to build a basic employee management software with GUI. When I load sample data, I believe they are being created as Class Objects (`Employee`) because when I debug I can see that all of the arguments are passed and the object is created. HOWEVER, when I try to modify them later (such as hired status), it returns an error `'str' object has no attribute 'hired_status'`

`Employee` Class:

```
"""Create Employee class so all employees can be Employee Objects"""
def __init__(self, fname='', lname='', phone='', email='', job='', interview_rating=0, hired_status='N'):
    self.first = fname
    self.last = lname
    self.phone_number = phone
    self.email_address = email
    self.interview = interview_rating
    self.__emp_job = job
    self.hired_status = hired_status

@property
def first_name(self):
    return self.__first

@first_name.setter
def first_name(self, fname):
    if fname.isalpha() and len(fname) >= 1:
        self.__first = fname.capitalize()
    else:
        self.__first = 'Unknown'

@property
def last_name(self):
    return self.__last

@last_name.setter
def last_name(self, lname):
    if lname.isalpha() and len(lname) >= 1:
        self.__last = lname.capitalize()
    else:
        self.__last = 'Unknown'

@property
def email_address(self):
    return self.__email_address

@email_address.setter
def email_address(self, email):
    if len(email) >=1 and '@' in email:
        self.__email_address = email
    else:
        self.__email_address = 'Unknown'

@property
def phone_number(self):
    return self.__phone_number.format(str)

@phone_number.setter
def phone_number(self, phone):
    if len(phone) >= 1:
        self.__phone_number = phone
    else:
        self.__phone_number = 'Unknown'

@property
def job(self):
    return self.__emp_job

@job.setter
def job(self, job):
    self.__emp_job = job

@property
def hired_status(self):
    return self.__hired_status

@hired_status.setter
def hired_status(self, hired):
    self.__hired_status = hired

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name},{self.last_name},{self.phone_number},{self.email_address},{self.job},' \
           f'{self.hired_status}'
```

Main Class:

```
def load_employees():
    """
    Loads same employees from the text file.
    - Creates an Employee object for each employee listed in the file.
    - Retrieves comma-separated values from each line and assigns it to the corresponding arg in Employee()
    - Adds the new employee object to the list of current employees.
    - Displays the employees on the screen for the user.
    """
    global first_name, last_name, phone, email, job, new_employee, current_employees, hired_status
    current_employees = []
    with open('employees.txt', 'r') as file:
        for f in file:
            first_name, last_name, phone, email, job, hired_status = f.split(',')
            sample_employee = Employee(first_name, last_name, phone, email, job, hired_status)
            sample_employee.first_name = first_name
            sample_employee.last_name = last_name
            sample_employee.phone_number = phone
            sample_employee.email_address = email
            sample_employee.job = job
            sample_employee.hired_status = hired_status
            current_employees.append(f)
            emp_list.insert(END, f)
```

Trying to hire

```
def hire_candidate():
    global first_name, last_name, phone, email, job, new_employee, current_employees, edit_mode, hired_status, emp_list
    new_employee = emp_list.get(ANCHOR)
    new_employee.hired_status = 'Y'
```

adding new employee with the GUI

```
def save_new_employee():
    """
    When user clicks "Save Employee" the program will create or edit an Employee object.
    - A new Employee will be added to the list of current employees and appear in the GUI.
    - If editing, the Employee object will be updated with the new information.
    - The user is prompted with a message saying they have added or updated an Employee.
    - The Employee Management form will then clear all textboxes.
    """
    global first_name, last_name, phone, email, job, new_employee, current_employees, edit_mode, hired_status
    global applicant_first_tbx, applicant_last_tbx, applicant_phone_tbx, applicant_email_tbx, jobs_cbx
    new_employee = None
    new_employee = Employee(first_name, last_name, phone, email, job, hired_status)

    new_employee.first_name = applicant_first_tbx.get()
    new_employee.last_name = applicant_last_tbx.get()
    new_employee.phone_number = applicant_phone_tbx.get()
    new_employee.email_address = applicant_email_tbx.get()
    new_employee.job = job

    if edit_mode:
        x = emp_list.curselection()
        current_employees[edit_index] = x
        emp_list.delete(x)
        emp_list.insert(edit_index, new_employee)
        current_employees.pop(edit_index)
        current_employees.append(new_employee)
        edit_mode = False
        messagebox.showinfo('Employee Information Updated.', f'Information for {new_employee.first_name} '
                                                             f'{new_employee.last_name} has been updated.')
    else:
        current_employees.append(new_employee)
        emp_list.insert(END, new_employee)
        messagebox.showinfo('New Employee Added', f'{new_employee.first_name} {new_employee.last_name} '
                                                  f'has been added to your roster.')

    applicant_first_tbx.delete(0, END)
    applicant_last_tbx.delete(0, END)
    applicant_phone_tbx.delete(0, END)
    applicant_email_tbx.delete(0, END)
```

Creating the relevant GUI

```
# create the main program window
win = Tk()
win.title('Employee Management Form')
win.config(bg='skyblue', pady=20, padx=50)

# global variables
current_employees = []
edit_mode = False
first_name = StringVar()
last_name = StringVar()
phone = StringVar()
email = StringVar()
job = StringVar()
hired_status = StringVar()
job_titles = ['Cook', 'Dishwasher', 'Server']
food_handler = ['Yes', 'No']
cook_certs = {1: 'Basic', 2: 'Advanced'}
interview_scores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_offset = 10
color = 'skyblue'
new_employee = None
edit_index = 0
employeeManagement = True

# options menu
menu_bar = Menu(win)
win.config(menu=menu_bar)
win.iconbitmap('emgmt.ico')

# Create a menu bar with required cascades and commands
file_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=False)
view = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=False)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=file_menu)

# Saves the information entered into the textboxes as a new employee, or overwrites an employee if editing
file_menu.add_command(label='Save Employee', command=save_new_employee)

# Turns on Edit Mode so user can modify information of an existing employee
file_menu.add_command(label='Edit Employee', command=edit_employee)

# Deletes employee obj from the data structure and removes their name from the GUI
file_menu.add_command(label='Delete Employee', command=delete_employee)

# updates the text file of employees, so upon reopening the program, all changes made previously are reflected
file_menu.add_command(label='Save All Changes', command=save_all_changes)

# Adds the option for the user to switch between employee management and the interview scorecard
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='View', menu=view)
view.add_command(label='Employee Management', command=employee_mgmt)
view.add_command(label='Employee Rating', command=employee_rating)

# frame to display list of current employees. Always visible as per instructions
emp_list_frm = Frame(win, bg='skyblue')
emp_list_frm.pack()

# create the listbox of employees
emp_list_lbl = Label(emp_list_frm, text='Current Employees', bg='systembuttonface', width=30, justify=CENTER)
emp_list_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=S)
emp_list = Listbox(emp_list_frm, width=75, listvariable=current_employees)
emp_list.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)

# employee management frame to add, edit, and delete employees
em_frame = Frame(win, bg='skyblue')
em_frame.pack()

# create layout for job application data
applicant_first_lbl = Label(em_frame, text='First Name:', justify=LEFT, pady=y_offset, bg=color)
applicant_first_lbl.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
applicant_first_tbx = Entry(em_frame, justify=LEFT, width=30, textvariable=first_name)
applicant_first_tbx.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
applicant_first_tbx.bind('<Key>', name_keys)

applicant_last_lbl = Label(em_frame, text='Last Name:', justify=LEFT, pady=y_offset, bg=color)
applicant_last_lbl.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
applicant_last_tbx = Entry(em_frame, justify=LEFT, width=30, textvariable=last_name)
applicant_last_tbx.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
applicant_last_tbx.bind('<Key>', name_keys)

applicant_phone_lbl = Label(em_frame, text='Phone Number:', justify=LEFT, pady=y_offset, bg=color)
applicant_phone_lbl.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)
applicant_phone_tbx = Entry(em_frame, justify=LEFT, width=30, textvariable=phone)
applicant_phone_tbx.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
applicant_phone_tbx.bind('<Key>', phone_keys)

applicant_email_lbl = Label(em_frame, text='Email:', justify=LEFT, pady=y_offset, bg=color)
applicant_email_lbl.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
applicant_email_tbx = Entry(em_frame, justify=LEFT, width=30, textvariable=email)
applicant_email_tbx.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W)

# create dropdown list for food handlers card
food_handler_label = Label(em_frame, text='Food Handler Card:', justify=LEFT, pady=y_offset, bg=color)
food_handler_label.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)
food_handler_cbx = ttk.Combobox(em_frame, values=food_handler, width=10)
food_handler_cbx.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)

# create dropdown list for applied positions
job_applied_label = Label(em_frame, text='Select Job:', justify=LEFT, pady=y_offset, bg=color)
job_applied_label.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W)

jobs_cbx = ttk.Combobox(em_frame, values=job_titles, width=15)
jobs_cbx.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
jobs_cbx.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', add_job_applied)

# Textbox showing list of all jobs the employee applied for
jobs_applied_txt = Entry(em_frame, justify=LEFT, width=25, textvariable=job_titles)
jobs_applied_txt.grid(row=9, columnspan=2, sticky=E)

# Highest Cook cert
cook_cert_label = Label(em_frame, text='If Cook, select highest certification:', justify=LEFT,
                        pady=y_offset, bg=color)
cook_cert_label.grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W)

# If applying for Cook, Buttons to show the highest level cooking cert
basic_btn = Radiobutton(em_frame, variable=cook_certs, text='Basic', value=1, bg=color, indicatoron=1, state=DISABLED)
basic_btn.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)

advanced_btn = Radiobutton(em_frame, variable=cook_certs, text='Advanced', value=2, bg=color, indicatoron=1, padx=2,
                           state=DISABLED)
advanced_btn.grid(row=12, column=1, sticky=W)
```

```
# Creates a frame for Rating System
rating_frame = Frame(win, bg='skyblue')

rating_lbl = Label(rating_frame, bg=color, text='Interview Rating Form:\n'
                                                'Rate an Employee from 1 to 5, where 1 is the '
                                                'worst and 5 is the best'' in the following categories.')
rating_lbl.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3)

comms_rate_lbl = Label(rating_frame, bg=color, text='1. Verbal/Communication Skills')
comms_rate_lbl.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
comms_cbx = ttk.Combobox(rating_frame, values=interview_scores, width=10)
comms_cbx.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

personal_rate_lbl = Label(rating_frame, bg=color, text='2. Interpersonal Skills and Friendliness')
personal_rate_lbl.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)
personal_cbx = ttk.Combobox(rating_frame, values=interview_scores, width=10)
personal_cbx.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)

math_lbl = Label(rating_frame, bg=color, text='3. Math/Problem Solving Skills')
math_lbl.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky=W)
math_cbx = ttk.Combobox(rating_frame, values=interview_scores, width=10)
math_cbx.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=W)

exp_lbl = Label(rating_frame, bg=color, text='4. Applicable World Experience')
exp_lbl.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky=W)
exp_cbx = ttk.Combobox(rating_frame, values=interview_scores, width=10)
exp_cbx.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky=W)

interview_average_btn = Button(rating_frame, bg='gray', text='Calculate Interview Average',
                               command=lambda: calculate_interview_average(interview_average_btn))
interview_average_btn.grid(row=11, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=W, pady=8,)
interview_average_tbx = Entry(rating_frame, bg='white', width=10)
interview_average_tbx.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky=E)

hire_btn = Button(rating_frame, bg='gold', text='Hire Candidate', state=DISABLED, command=hire_candidate)
hire_btn.grid(row=12, column=0, sticky=W)
```

The idea is that you click and employee form a listbox, then click a button to hire them. I think it is returning the string from the listbox, but I want it to return the object in that location.

Error message

```
 File "C:\Users\Jack\PycharmProjects\Class_Project_jxhawki1\employee_management.py", line 188, in hire_candidate
    new_employee.hired_status = 'Y'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'hired_status'
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show relevant code?  Where is the Employee class definition, where do you instantiate the employee record, where is your tkinter code, showing the processing of the gui?

Comment: Your load_employees function does not create an Employee instantiation for the entries in employees.txt, it simply creates a list of string variables containing employee information.

Comment: @itprorh66. Right. At that point the idea is loading the sample employees FROM the .txt to create the employee objects. I am wondering if the save_new_employee() is not working correctly then. In my hire_candidate() function I want to modify the object

Comment: can you at least post the error message you are getting as code in your question?

Comment: @itprorh66 posted the error message. Sorry for not being clear at first. This is my first time posting a question to this website. Am still learning how to format everything and what to include. I appreciate you taking the time to revisit.

Comment: Somehow between the creation of the employee object and referencing it, it is becoming a string. When I debug and go line by line through load_employees, it brings me to my Employees class. In that class I can see that each attribute IS being set. The properties and setters are working correctly, and when I say ```print(new_employee)``` each employee from the .txt file is being printed. So I think my objects are being created but something about how I am storing/referencing them later is not what I want

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre]. This is way too much code. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the code you have shown.  First, your code relies on, in my humble opinion, too many global variables that are not necessary or desirable.  Second, while technically all right the way you are mixing grid and pack geometries within the same window will work, it is a dangerous practice.  I much prefer sticking with one geometry throughout everything.  Finally, I believe your basic problem is that you have provided no data structure to correlate the string value returned from listbox select function to the specific employee instance containing the selected employee's data.  The following is not a complete solution to your overall application needs, but does clean up several of the above issues.

First, a rewrite of your Employee class

```
class Employee:
    """Create Employee class so all employees can be Employee Objects"""
    def __init__(self, fname= 'Unknown', lname= 'Unknown', phone= 'Unknown', email= 'Unknown', job= '', interview_rating= 0, hired_status= False):
        self._first = None
        self._last = None
        self._emAdr = None
        self._phnNo = None
        self._status = False
        self._job = None
        self._intrvRate = int(interview_rating)
        self.first_name = fname
        self.last_name = lname
        self.phone_number = phone
        self.email_address = email
        self.employee_job = job
        self.hired_status = hired_status

    @property
    def first_name(self):
        return self._first
    
    @first_name.setter
    def first_name(self, fname):
        try:
            if fname.isalpha() and len(fname) >= 1:
                self._first = fname.capitalize()
        except:
            raise ValueError(f"First Name '{fname}' must be alpha and be at least 1 character long")
                
    @property
    def last_name(self):
        return self._last

    @last_name.setter
    def last_name(self, lname):
        if lname.isalpha() and len(lname) >= 1:
            self._last = lname.capitalize()
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Last Name '{lname}' must be alpha and be at least 1 character long")
            
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}"
            
    @property
    def email_address(self):
        return self._emAdr

    @email_address.setter
    def email_address(self, email):
        if email == '':
            self.emAdr = 'Unknown'
        elif '@' in email and len(email) >= 1:
            self._emAdr = email
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Email Address '{email}' must contain an '@' and be at least 1 character long")

    @property
    def phone_number(self):
        return self._phnNo

    @phone_number.setter
    def phone_number(self, phone):
        if len(phone) == 0:
            self._phnNo = 'Unknown'
        elif len(phone) >= 1:
            self._phnNo = phone
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Phone Number '{phone}' must be at least 1 character long")

    @property
    def employee_job(self):
        return self._job

    @employee_job.setter
    def employee_job(self, job):
        self._job = job

    @property
    def hired_status(self):
        return self._status

    @hired_status.setter
    def hired_status(self, status):
        if isinstance(status, bool):
            self._status = status
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Hiring Status '{status}' must be either 'True' or 'False'")
        
    @property
    def hire(self):
        self.hired_status = True

    @property
    def fire(self):
        self.hired_status = False
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name}, {self.last_name}, {self.phone_number}, {self.email_address}, {self.employee_job}, {self.hired_status}'
```

An updated load data function:

```
def load_employees(fn):
    """
    Loads employees from text file fn.
    - Retrieves comma-separated values from each line and assigns it to the corresponding arg in Employee()
    - Adds the employee object to the employee_dict.
    """
    employee_dict = dict()
    with open(fn, 'r') as file:
        for l in file.readlines():
            itms = l.split(',')
            emp = Employee(fname= itms[0].strip(), 
                          lname = itms[1].strip(),
                          phone= itms[2].strip(),
                          email = itms[3].strip(),
                          job = itms[4].strip(),
                          interview_rating = itms[5].strip(),
                          hired_status = True if itms[6].strip().lower() == 'y'  else  False)
            employee_dict[emp.full_name] = emp           
    return employee_dict
```

A couple of Enumerated Constant classes

```
class job_titles(Enum):
    Cook = auto()
    Dishwasher = auto()
    Server = auto()

class food_handlers(Enum):
        Cook = True
        Dishwasher = False
        Server = True
        
class cook_certs(Enum):
    Basic = 1
    Advanced = 2
```

A new class to manage the GUI interface

```
# Class to display the Employee Gui and Manage all related employee methods
class EmployeeForm():

        
    def __init__(self, employee_list):
        self.emp_list = employee_list
        self.selected_employee = None
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("Employee Management Form")
        self.win.config(bg='skyblue', pady=20, padx=50)
        self.build_menuBar(self.win)
        self.build_list_frame(self.win)
        self.win.mainloop()

    def do_nothing(self):
        #Stub for menu items not yetbimplements 
        pass
    
    def get_currewnt_employees(self):
        pass
    
    
    def build_menuBar(self, frm):
        """ Format the Menu bar """
        
        def add_command(mnu, itm):
            mnu.add_command(label= itm[0], command= itm[1])
 
        def add_sub_menu(mnu, cmd_dict):
            for ky in cmd_dict.keys():
                if len(cmd_dict[ky]) > 0:
                    mi = tk.Menu(mnu, tearoff= 0)
                    mnu.add_cascade(label=ky, menu=mi)
                    for itm in cmd_dict[ky]:
                        if type(itm) == tuple:
                            add_command(mi, itm)
                        else:
                            add_sub_menu(mi, itm) 
                            
                         
        menuoptions = {'File': [('Save Employee', self.do_nothing),
                                     ('Edit Employee', self.do_nothing),
                                     ('Delete Employee', self.do_nothing),
                                     ('Save All Changes', self.do_nothing)],
                            'View': [('Employee Management', self.do_nothing),
                                     ('Employee Rating', self.do_nothing)],
                            }
        
        mbar = tk.Menu(frm)
        add_sub_menu(mbar, menuoptions)
        frm.config(menu=mbar)
        return mbar
    
    def select_employee(self, event):
        selection = event.widget.curselection()
        if self.selected_employee != self.cur_emps[selection[0]]:
            self.selected_employee = self.cur_emps[selection[0]]
            
        # if selection:
        #     index = selection[0]
        #     data = event.widget.get(index)
        
    
    def build_list_frame(self, parent):
        """ frame to display list of current employees. Always visible as per instructions""" 
        self.emp_list_frm = tk.Frame(parent, bg='skyblue', relief= tk.RAISED, borderwidth= 5)
        self.emp_list_frm.grid(row= 0 , sticky= (tk.E, tk.W))
        emp_list_lbl = tk.Label(self.emp_list_frm, text='Current Employees', 
                                bg='systembuttonface', justify= tk.CENTER)
        emp_list_lbl.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky= (tk.E, tk.W))
        self.cur_emps = list(x for x in sorted(self.emp_list.keys()))       
        self.emp_list_dsply  = tk.Listbox(self.emp_list_frm, width=75, 
                                          listvariable =tk.StringVar(value= self.cur_emps) )
        self.emp_list_dsply.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)
        self.emp_list_dsply.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.select_employee)
```

To run the above:

```
emp_file = 'employees.txt'
emplist = load_employees(emp_file)
EmployeeForm(load_employees(emp_file))
```

Once you select an employee from the listbox selection options, the contents of  self.selected_employee will reflect the employee object which then can be referenced by the delete method, and the edit method for further actions.